# how to show Html email status records on visualforce page with contact have data of html email status

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]////////vf page/////////

```
<apex:page controller="StandardAccountDisplayController"> 
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact List"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="rec"> 
        <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.id}"/> 
            </apex:column>
          <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.name}"/> 
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Title</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.Title}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">phone</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.phone}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
             <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Html Email Status</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.EmailStatuses}"/> 
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasPrevious}" value="first" action="{!records.first}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasPrevious}" value="Previous" action="{!records.previous}"/>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(records.pageNumber * records .pageSize) < records.ResultSize}" value="{!records .pageNumber * records .pageSize} Of {!records .ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(records.pageNumber * records .pageSize) >= records.ResultSize}" value="{!records .ResultSize} Of {!records .ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>          
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasNext}" value="next" action="{!records.next}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasNext}" value="last" action="{!records.last}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

/////controller/////

```
public with sharing class StandardAccountDisplayController{ 
// public List<Contact> records {get; set;} 
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController records{ 
        get {
                if(records == null) {
                    records = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT id, name,Title,phone,(SELECT id, taskId, createdDate, firstOpenDate, lastOpenDate, timesOpened, emailTemplateName FROM EmailStatuses)FROM Contact ORDER BY createdDate LIMIT 10000]));
                }
                return records ;
            }
            set;
    }
    public List<Contact> getcontacts() {
         records.setpagesize(10);
         return(List<Contact>)records.getRecords();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<apex:page controller="StandardAccountDisplayController"> 
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact List"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="rec"> 
        <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.id}"/> 
            </apex:column>
          <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.name}"/> 
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Title</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.Title}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">phone</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!rec.phone}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
             <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Html Email Status</apex:facet>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!rec.EmailStatuses}" var="emailStatus" id="theRepeat">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!emailStatus}" id="theValue"/><br/>
                    </apex:repeat>              
               <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!rec.EmailStatuses}"/> -->
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasPrevious}" value="first" action="{!records.first}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasPrevious}" value="Previous" action="{!records.previous}"/>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(records.pageNumber * records .pageSize) < records.ResultSize}" value="{!records .pageNumber * records .pageSize} Of {!records .ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!(records.pageNumber * records .pageSize) >= records.ResultSize}" value="{!records .ResultSize} Of {!records .ResultSize}"></apex:outputText>          
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasNext}" value="next" action="{!records.next}"/>
            <apex:commandButton rendered="{!records.hasNext}" value="last" action="{!records.last}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: But above code only give the id of html email status not values of taskId, createdDate, firstOpenDate, lastOpenDate, timesOpened, emailTemplateName.